# multiprocessing.Process causing: OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory even when I run only 1 process

Tags: python, multithreading, process, multiprocessing

I'm trying to process a very large text file (~11 GB) in a remote server (AWS).
The processing needed to be done on the file is pretty complex and with a regular python program the total run time is ~1 month. In order to reduce runtime I'm trying to divide the work on the file between some processes.
Computer specs:
[Computer specs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmQLC.png)

Code:

```
def initiate_workers(works, num_workers, output_path):
    """
    :param works: Iterable of lists of strings (The work to be processed divided in num_workers pieces)
    :param num_workers: Number of workers
    :return: A list of Process objects where each object is ready to process its share.
    """
    res = []
    for i in range(num_workers):
        # process_batch is the processing function
        res.append(multiprocessing.Process(target=process_batch, args=(output_path + str(i), works[i])))
    return res



def run_workers(workers):
    """
    Run the workers and wait for them to finish
    :param workers: Iterable of Process objects
    """
    logging.info("Starting multiprocessing..")
    for i in range(len(workers)):
        workers[i].start()
        logging.info("Started worker " + str(i))
    for j in range(len(workers)):
        workers[j].join()
```

I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "w2v_process.py", line 93, in <module>
    run_workers(workers)
  File "w2v_process.py", line 58, in run_workers
    workers[i].start()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 105, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/context.py", line 223, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/context.py", line 277, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 19, in __init__
    self._launch(process_obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 66, in _launch
    self.pid = os.fork()
OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
```

and it doesn't matter if num_workers=1 or 6 or 14, it always crashes.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Found the problem. I saw somewhere on SO that fork (last line on traceback) is actually doubling the RAM. While processing the file I loaded it into the memory what filled ~18GB and given that the entire capacity of the RAM is 30GB indeed there is a memory allocation error.
I divided the large file into smaller files (the number of workers) and gave each Process object the path to this file. This way, each process reads the data in a lazy fashion and everything works great!

Comment: Do you by chance have old copies of your program (or something else) filling up memory on your instance?

Comment: If you could add your solution as an answer (and mark it correct), it would help others find the answer more quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. I saw somewhere on SO that fork (last line on traceback) is actually doubling the RAM. While processing the file I loaded it into the memory what filled ~18GB and given that the entire capacity of the RAM is 30GB indeed there is a memory allocation error. I divided the large file into smaller files (the number of workers) and gave each Process object the path to this file. This way, each process reads the data in a lazy fashion and everything works great!